# Tag synonym request: [eu4] --> [europa-universalis-4]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

This is a pretty common abbreviation for the game, so much so that whenever I mention it in text (and most of the time in speech as well) I use eu4 rather than the draw out Europa Universalis Four.

When I first searched for the tag, there was about 30 seconds of confusion when `eu4` came up blank. Admittedly, not exactly earth-shattering, but still rather annoying.

Answer (score 2):

**Done:**

I've added the requested synonym, and updated the main tag as per our [community's support for Roman numerals](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/should-we-standardize-our-tag-formatting-regarding-arabic-vs-roman-numerals):

- [eu4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu4), [europa-universalis-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europa-universalis-4) → [europa-universalis-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europa-universalis-iv)