# Is there any reason why the Final Fantasy tags don't have a corresponding 'FF' tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

### Most Final Fantasy games have quite a lot of ways to be expressed:

- **Final Fantasy** *IX*  (Name, Roman Numeral)
- **Final Fantasy** *9*   (Name, Arabic Numeral)
- **FF** *IX*  (Shortname, Arabic Numeral)
- **FF** *9* (Shortname, Arabic Numeral)

As per [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/should-we-standardize-our-tag-formatting-regarding-arabic-vs-roman-numerals), it appears that this (and other) series of Games have been dealt with, when it comes to their name.

However one particular thing that stands out is that you can't search for Final Fantasy games by their Shortname (FF).

However you can do so with Defense of the Ancients *(DoTA)*, Left For Dead *L4D*.

Is there any particular reason why there aren't "FF9", "FF7", etc.. tags as synonyms?

Comment: The tags discussed in the linked meta actually haven't had anything done to them (yet). I'm not sure what steps need to be taken, but I have a feeling it will need to be done by mods.

Answer (score 1):

The meta you linked makes a great point overall but doesn't actually have anything really *actionable* other than 'use the game's official numbering as the base tag', which is probably why the tag synonyms didn't get created.

You can suggest synonyms, but you need [2500 rep and some upvotes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) within each tag if you're going to suggest a synonym:

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms...
>
> Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Otherwise if you would like us to create some synonyms, list out all the tags and which synonyms you believe would help (perhaps as an answer?) - that way the community can discuss each in turn and vote on it. If you get a majority agreement about the usefulness of the synonyms, we can look at creating them.

Comment: At the momment I was just asking if there was a particular reason for it not to have happened yet (Because I couldn't find anything about it in Meta), I may just aswell suggest it. In another thread, correct?

Comment: @Oak There's really no reason to have the short tags. Synonyms are primarily used to fix confusion if issues arrive with tag usage, not pre-emptively in case someone only thought to search "ff" but not start typing "final-fantasy".

Comment: @StrixVaria: Are synonyms also not used as shortcuts? Practically speaking, that appears to be the case. If I'm looking for things that are tagged for *Defense of the Ancients* and I try searching tags for dota first and get no results, would I not immediately know to search defense-of-the-ancients? Yet, we have both tags anyway. How is this different between ff and final-fantasy? From the synonyms page: "If you know of **common, alternate spellings or phrasings** for this tag" - that seems to be a clear indicator that ff-* would be an acceptable synonym.