# Rename Heroes of Might and Magic tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming the Heroes of Might and Magic series tags as following:

- [heroes-might-magic-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-1) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-1) (27 characters);
- [heroes-might-magic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-2) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-2) (27);
- [heroes-might-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-3) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-3) (27);
- [heroes-might-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-4) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-4) (27);
- [heroes-might-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-5) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-5) (27).

Since 6th game official title has been changed to Might & Magic Heroes, we could also rename (I've checked there are a lot of `and` usage in place of `&` in tags, for example [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer)):

- [might-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-6) → [might-and-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-6) (24);
- [might-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-7) → [might-and-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-7) (24).

However, this renaming is impossible for [might-magic-heroes-7-trial-by-fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-7-trial-by-fire), but it was used only once and I don't know if we need separate tag for this expansion at all.

For some of these tags synonyms with roman digits exist ( https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/heroes-might-magic-3/synonyms ), they should be updated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew! What a mess.

The tags have all been renamed to [arghtype](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12815/181240) & [Steve's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12823/181240) suggestions, with one difference - Might and Magic X: Legacy continues to use 'X' instead of '10' as that's the official title.

Regarding synonyms however, some of the old shorter tags weren't that relevant as synonyms ("might-and-magic-2" is still within "might-and-magic-2-another-world" etc), so I have replaced them with the below synonyms that either utilise the full game's subtitle or add common series & community abbreviations:

#### Might & Magic

- [mm-the-secret-of-the-inner-sanctum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-the-secret-of-the-inner-sanctum) → [might-and-magic-book-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-book-one)
- [mm-2-gates-to-another-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-2-gates-to-another-world) → [might-and-magic-2-another-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-2-another-world)
- [mm-6-the-mandate-of-heaven](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-6-the-mandate-of-heaven) → [might-and-magic-6-mandate-of-heaven](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-6-mandate-of-heaven)
- [mm-7-for-blood-and-honor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-7-for-blood-and-honor) → [might-and-magic-7-blood-and-honor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-7-blood-and-honor)
- [mm-8-day-of-the-destroyer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-8-day-of-the-destroyer) → [might-and-magic-8-day-of-destroyer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-8-day-of-destroyer)
- [mm-duel-of-champions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-duel-of-champions) → [might-and-magic-duel-of-champions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-duel-of-champions)
- [mm-x-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-x-legacy), [mm-10-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-10-legacy), [might-and-magic-10-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-10-legacy) → [might-and-magic-x-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-x-legacy)
- [mm-world-of-xeen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-world-of-xeen) → [might-and-magic-world-of-xeen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-world-of-xeen)
- [mm-dark-messiah](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-dark-messiah), [might-and-magic-dark-messiah](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-dark-messiah) →  [dark-messiah-of-might-and-magic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-messiah-of-might-and-magic)

#### Heroes of Might and Magic

- [homm-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homm-1), [heroes-might-magic-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-1), [homm-a-strategic-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homm-a-strategic-quest) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic)
- [homm-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homm-2), [heroes-might-magic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-2) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-2)
- [homm-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homm-3), [heroes-might-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-3) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-3)
- [homm-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homm-4), [heroes-might-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-4) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-4)
- [homm-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homm-5), [heroes-might-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-5) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-5)

#### Might and Magic: Heroes

- [mmh-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmh-6), [might-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-6) → [might-and-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-6)
- [mmh-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmh-7), [might-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-7) → [might-and-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-7)
- [mmh-7-trial-by-fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmh-7-trial-by-fire) → [might-magic-heroes-7-trial-by-fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-7-trial-by-fire)
- [mmh-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmh-online), [might-magic-heroes-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-online) → [might-and-magic-heroes-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-online)

Hopefully this helps sort out this confusing mess of a series!

Comment: Thank you for retagging this confusingly named series. I’m sure this will clear up some of the confusion.

Comment: I had suggested using 10 for Might and Magic X for consistency with the other series tags. Most games in the series use numerals, all of the tags had used numbers.

Comment: @Steve - I would have [preferred](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12181#comment40897_12808) to change them all to Roman numerals given that the series uses them, but instead I decided to follow the conventions that were set on the preexisting tags as that's how the community had been using them previously: the old tags all used Arabic numerals except for Might & Magic X. There could be a time to discuss whether to alter them to be Roman or Arabic but for the purposes of getting the lengthening done I had to make a call - that seemed like the fairest compromise for now.

Comment: A fair decision. I seem to be in the minority for preferring numbers over numerals, so it makes sense to stick with the numeral

Answer (score 3):

The *Might & Magic: Heroes* series naming is a bit complicated. The series is *technically* a combination of both the [*Heroes of Might and Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic) series and the [*Might and Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Might_and_Magic) series.

I agree with the suggested renames, but would like to propose a few additions. (I've classified the games as best I can by series)

#### Might & Magic (1986-2002; 2012-present)

- [might-and-magic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic) → [might-and-magic-book-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-book-one) (24) *Might and Magic Book One: The Secret of the Inner Sanctum* (1986)
- [might-and-magic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-2) → [might-and-magic-2-another-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-2-another-world) (31) *Might and Magic II: Gates to Another World* (1996)
- [might-and-magic-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-6) → [might-and-magic-6-mandate-of-heaven](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-6-mandate-of-heaven) (35) *Might and Magic VI: The Mandate of Heaven* (1998)
- [might-and-magic-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-7) → [might-and-magic-7-blood-and-honor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-7-blood-and-honor) (33) *Might and Magic VII: For Blood and Honor* (1999)
- [might-and-magic-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-8) → [might-and-magic-8-day-of-destroyer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-8-day-of-destroyer) (34) *Might and Magic VIII: Day of the Destroyer* (2000)
- [mm-duel-of-champions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mm-duel-of-champions) → [might-and-magic-duel-of-champions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-duel-of-champions) (33) *Might & Magic Duel of Champions*  (Before 2012?)
- [might-and-magic-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-x) → [might-and-magic-10-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-10-legacy) (24) *Might & Magic X: Legacy* (2014)

#### Heroes of Might and Magic (1995-2008)

- [heroes-might-magic-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-1) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic) (25) *Heroes of Might and Magic: A Strategic Quest* (1995)
- [heroes-might-magic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-2) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-2) (27) *Heroes of Might and Magic II* (1996)
- [heroes-might-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-3) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-3) (27) *Heroes of Might and Magic III* (1999)
- [heroes-might-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-4) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-4) (27) *Heroes of Might and Magic IV* (2002)
- [heroes-might-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-5) → [heroes-of-might-and-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic-5) (27) *Heroes of Might and Magic V* (2006)

#### Might and Magic: Heroes (2011-present)

- [might-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-6) → [might-and-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-6) (24) *Might & Magic: Heroes VI* (2011)
- [might-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-7) → [might-and-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-7) (24) *Might & Magic: Heroes VII* (2014)
- [might-magic-heroes-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-online) → [might-and-magic-heroes-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-heroes-online) (29) *Might and Magic: Heroes Online* (2014)

---

There are a few tags which already use the full title or would exceed the character limit. These can probably be left unchanged.

- [might-and-magic-world-of-xeen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-world-of-xeen) *Might and Magic: World of Xeen* (1993)
- [dark-messiah-of-might-and-magic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-messiah-of-might-and-magic) *Dark Messiah of Might and Magic* (2006)
- [might-magic-heroes-7-trial-by-fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-7-trial-by-fire) *Might and Magic: Heroes VII – Trial by Fire* (2016)