# Tag merge & synonym request: Use official titles for Grand Theft Auto series and Saints Row IV tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, tag-synonyms

As per community consensus at the meta post: [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/should-we-standardize-our-tag-formatting-regarding-arabic-vs-roman-numerals) - the official spelling of the game title should be used in the tags whenever possible, instead of replacing Roman numerals with Arabic numerals or adding Arabic numerals to titles that don't have them.

In line with that, requesting that these tags be merged and synonymized:

| Current tag (with Arabic numerals) → | Official game title tag |
| --- | --- |
| [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) → | [grand-theft-auto-v](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-v) |
| [grand-theft-auto-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4) → | [grand-theft-auto-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-iv) |
| [grand-theft-auto-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-3) → | [grand-theft-auto-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-iii) |
| [grand-theft-auto-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-1) → | [grand-theft-auto](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto) |
| [saints-row-4-saints-save-christmas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saints-row-4-saints-save-christmas) → | [saints-row-iv-saints-save-christmas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saints-row-iv-saints-save-christmas) |

Comment: In the year since the Arabic vs. Roman numerals meta topic was raised, I don't think that it's actually been followed through. I searched for a bit and couldn't find a single game tag with more than 5 questions that used Roman numerals instead of Arabic. I don't know if the lack of action is because the community sees it as impractical, or nobody has gotten around to it. I guess we'll see how this topic goes to see what the community thinks about actually making the change.

Comment: I think that renaming them with the official title and leaving the old ones (except for 5-ifruit, that is called "Grand Theft Auto: iFruit" on Google Play) as synonyms is a better idea.

Comment: Note that for GTA 2 - it was actually titled as "Grand Theft Auto 2" (using the actual numerical value instead of a Roman Numeral) - hence why it is not listed in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the following:

| Former Tag | Renamed to |
| --- | --- |
| [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) → | [grand-theft-auto-v](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-v) |
| [grand-theft-auto-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4) → | [grand-theft-auto-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-iv) |
| [grand-theft-auto-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-3) → | [grand-theft-auto-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-iii) |
| [grand-theft-auto-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-1) → | [grand-theft-auto](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto) |
| [saints-row-4-saints-save-christmas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saints-row-4-saints-save-christmas) → | [saints-row-iv-saints-save-christmas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saints-row-iv-saints-save-christmas) |

All of the previous tag names are now synonyms.