# Tag synonym request: Age of Empires II and Age of Empires III tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-rename-request

As per [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/should-we-standardize-our-tag-formatting-regarding-arabic-vs-roman-numerals), the official spelling of the game title should be used in the tags whenever possible, instead of replacing Roman numerals with Arabic numerals.

Requesting that these tags be synonymized (current tag » official game title tag):
[age-of-empires-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2) » [age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings)
[age-of-empires-2-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2-hd) » [age-of-empires-ii-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-ii-hd)
[age-of-empires-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-3) » [age-of-empires-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-iii)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems reasonable, I've renamed these.

Comment: [tag:age-of-empires-iii-age-of-discovery] seems to be the [name of a board game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22545/age-empires-iii-age-discovery). I believe the video game is just named [tag:age-of-empires-iii].

Comment: Hmm. Either I've run into some weird localization confusion, or my sources are mistaken. Either way, I've fixed it.